# Can't install pipenv due to an EnvironmentError

Tags: python, pip, pythonanywhere, pipenv, site-packages

I tried running `pip3 install pipenv`, with my default target set to user site-packages, but I get an error:

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/dull/.loc
al/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pytz-2018.7.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Edit: I'm using doing this in a PythonAnywhere console, which might be useful info

Comment: What does `pip3 show pytz` return?

Comment: `pip3 show pytz` shows lots of errors. It first shows `AttributeError: _DistInfoDistribution__dep_map`. Then it says "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred" a few times, and the last error message is the same one I saw when installing pipenv.